# restart deployment using dashboard UI

Tags: argocd

I know that we can use the argocd cli to restart the deployment by using this command

```
argocd app actions run my-app restart --kind Deployment --all
```

Is there any way to use the ArgoCD dashboard to do a similar thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

On a Deployment object in the UI, click on the dots icon to show actions and choose "Restart".